# OpenGL- inaccurate depth values from z buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, depth-buffer

I am drawing a quad in OpenGL and then using glReadPixels to access the depth buffer. But, the problem is I'm always getting 1 from all the position of the OpenGL window. For example, for zbuffer[0][0] (please see the code below), the value should be 0, because that part of the window has no object. Again, for zbuffer[639][470], the value should also be 0, but I am receiving 1 for both the case.

Could you please point me what I am doing wrong here?

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;



void display ( )   // Create The Display Function
{

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gluLookAt(0.0 ,0.0 ,0.0 ,0.0 ,0.0 ,-1.0 ,0.0 ,1.0 ,0.0);


    glBegin(GL_QUADS); 

        glColor3f(0.813205,0.813205,0.813205);
        glVertex3f(-0.389662380802125,0.249152038469432,  -1.12528215173346); // top left corner

        glColor3f(0.309385,0.309385,0.309385);
        glVertex3f(0.433401472883409,0.272288002674917,  -0.923754348668237); // top right corner

        glColor3f(0.288292,0.288292,0.288292);
        glVertex3f(0.441173907261717,-0.296124431126115,  -0.915317251508196);// bottom right corner

        glColor3f(0.74028,0.74028,0.74028);
        glVertex3f(-0.388657135983495,-0.317680965994535,  -1.09611219327051); // bottom left corner


    glEnd();

    GLfloat zbuffer[640][480];

    glReadPixels(0,0,640,480,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT, zbuffer);

    cout<<"Depth1:"<<zbuffer[0][0]<<endl;
    cout<<"Depth2:"<<zbuffer[639][470]<<endl;

    glFlush();

    glutSwapBuffers ( );
}

void reshape ( int w, int h )   // Create The Reshape Function (the viewport)
{
    glViewport(0 ,0 ,(GLsizei)w,( GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity ( );
    gluPerspective(48.6f, (GLfloat) 640 / 480, 0.01f, 1000.0f);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW) ;
}

void keyboard ( unsigned char key, int x, int y )  // Create Keyboard Function
{
  switch ( key ) {
    case 27:        // When Escape Is Pressed...
      exit ( 0 );   // Exit The Program
      break;        // Ready For Next Case
    default:        // Now Wrap It Up
      break;
  }
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {

        float mx = x ;
        float my = y ;
//      ox = (mx/320-1.0);
//      oy = -(my/240 -1.0);
        switch(button){
            case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
                if(state==GLUT_DOWN){
                    printf("%f,",mx);
                    printf("%f\n",my);
                }
                break;
        }
}

int main ( int argc, char** argv )   
{
    glutInit            ( &argc, argv ); 
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize  (640, 480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow    ( "My Window" ); directory as title)
    glutReshapeFunc ( reshape ) ;
    glutDisplayFunc     ( display );  // Matching Earlier Functions To Their Counterparts
    glutKeyboardFunc    ( keyboard );
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMainLoop        ( );          // Initialize The Main Loop


  return 0;
}
```

And here is the object drawn in OpenGL:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, for zbuffer[0][0] (please see the code below), the value should be 0, because that part of the window has no object.

No, it shouldn't. THe default `glClearDepth` value is 1.0, so `glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` sets every pixel in the depth buffer to 1.0. This also makes sense because using the dfeault conventions, the near plane is mapped to `z=0` in window space, and the far plane to `z=1`, and the depth test is set to `GL_LESS`, so that fragments will pass which are nearer that what is currently drawn at that position.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Could you please direct me how can I get depth values (from the z-buffer) for the object which I have drawn? I am getting 1 for all the position.

Comment: @Tariq: well, just read back the values at some pixel which is actually affected by the object you have drawn. I skimmed over your code briefly, and think that the viewport center 320,240 should cover your primitive.

Comment: I get 0.990594 for the viewport center (320, 240). It might sound stupid, but I could not quite understand what value should I expect for the object I drew and for the black part of the viewport (please see the image attached)? I thought that I would get values greater than 0 for the drawn object and 0 for the blank part of the screen.

Comment: Nope, you'll get 1 for the "blank" parts, and some value from 0 to 1 for the parts you have drawn. Yes, it could even be 1.0, because due to the default <= comparision mode of the depth test, even a fragment at 1.0 would be drawn. You probably don't expect a value so close to 1.0 at that position, but due to the perspective projection matrix, that value is totally plausible.

Comment: @Tariq: since you don't seem to expect these values, the broader question seems to me: what are you actually trying to do with the z-value you are querying?

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I was actually working with depth cameras and wanted to get depth values for the objects in the scene. For that, I tracked an object and got the positions of the object and drew it on OpenGL and now trying to see if OpenGL gives me similar depth values as the depth cameras.
You might know that for the parts which the depth cameras can't measure the depth, they assign a 0 value to those parts and the rest of the scene has some depth values.

Comment: Actually, I have to correct myself. The default depth function is `GL_LESS`, not `GL_LEQUAL`, so a fragment with depth exactly at 1.0 would not pass the depth test against the initial depth value of 1.0.  But the rest is correct nonetheless.

Comment: Okay. Could you please tell me if you see any wrong or missing statements in my codes? Any OpneGL setting I have missed or placed in inappropriate places?

Comment: @Tariq: THere should be a `glLoadIdentity()` before `glLookAt()` in your `display` function, otherwise you will screw up the transformation state for any subsequent frame. However, you should be aware that almost _all_ of your code uses deprecated OpenGL functionality, which is _removed_ in modern version of GL.

Comment: thanks a lot, I really appreciate you for taking time to explain me. I will update the functions which are deprecated.

Comment: I have a followup question. Let's say, I have read the depth values in zbuffer[640][480]. Now, I want to display the depth value of a particular pixel of the OpenGL window. My OpenGL window has resolution of 640X480. Let's say, I want to display the depth values of the pixel which is located at (x,y)= (570, 480). Is there a simple way to do that?

would the value stored at zbuffer[570][480] be the depth value of the pixel (570, 480)? Or there is another thing which I am missing?

Comment: yes, the depth buffer holds the depth value for exactly those pixels. But the depth value itself is not linear - it is hyperbolically distorted due to the perspective, so these values are probably not what want. YOu might want to _unproject_ the values back to eye space.

Comment: Never mind, just found a workaround. I used gluUnProject() to retrieve the z-buffer values.